# Find MGF of random variable X

Tags: probability

- We are given rth raw moment i.e. $E(X^r)=(r+1)!* (2^r)$.
- We have to find MGF of random variable $X$.
- so what is the simplest way to solve this problem.

Comment: and what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im reading in wikipedia now that MGF is the [exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Definition) for the moments of some probability distribution.

We have that $[t^r/r!]M_{X}(t)=(r+1)!\ (2^r)$ then the MGF is $M_{X}(t)=\sum_{r\ge 0}(r+1)\ (2t)^r$.

This sum is a variant of a power series. You must notice that $\frac{d}{dx} \left(x\sum_{n}x^n\right)=\sum_{n}(n+1) x^n$ and you knows that the formal power series $\sum_{n}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Then

$$M_{X}(t)=\sum_{r\ge 0}(r+1)\ (2t)^r=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{t}{1-2t}=\frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}$$

Comment: how do you solve that summation ?

Comment: You dont need to solve something @gaurav, just take the definition... Oh, you want the closed form for the sum... ok